# How do I correctly assign my root node to a value?

Tags: java, hashmap, binary-tree, assign, root-node

I am trying to create a Binary Tree from a Hashmap, and in order to do so, I'm trying to assign the root node to a specific Node in the Hashmap, basically the entry which has the entry.getValue() as null.

I have been able to convert my keys into nodes from ints, now I'm trying to set the key which has null as it's value to be the root.

I have also declared a root as a Binary Tree type, here is my code:

```
public static BinaryTreeNode parentMapToTree(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
    HashMap<BinaryTreeNode, Integer> l = new HashMap<>();
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
      l.put(new BinaryTreeNode(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue());
    }
    BinaryTreeNode root = null;
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
      if (entry.getValue() == null);{
        root == l.get(entry.getKey());
      }

    }
  }
```

Can anyone please explain how to declare that particular `entry` as the root node for me to build by Binary Tree upon?

Comment: did you mean `root = l.get(...`?

Comment: @tgdavies when I do that, I get Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.Integer', required: 'BinaryTreeNode' error though

Comment: I mean that you are using == where you wanted to assign a value

Comment: yea I'm trying to assign that value to BinaryTreeNode root

Comment: * assign the key of the value as the root

Comment: Yes, so assign the key instead of getting a value from `l`.

Comment: I tried to do if (entry.getValue() == null);{
        root == entry.getKey();
      } but it still doesn;t work

Comment: as u said to assign the key

Comment: can I do this instead *****  if (entry.getValue() == null);{
       BinaryTreeNode k = new BinaryTreeNode(entry.getKey());
       root.equals(k);
      }?*****

Comment: A `==` is not the same as `=`. One is comparison and the other is assignment. And what do your believe that `root.equals(k)` does?

Comment: Both = and == don't work for me though

Comment: oh wait root,equals(k) is a boolean isn't it

Comment: so it won't work